# про создание нового пользователя в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

1.если создать нового пользователя будут все те же программы с чистыми настройками и он никак не будет связан с другим пользователем на том же компе?
2.в ubuntu кроме как через командную строку можно что то установить(как например в windows .ехе)?

Comment: Все программы общедоступные для всех пользователей может установить только тот кто имеет пароль от главного супер-пользователя. Другие пользователи могут устанавливать программы для себя. Они могут дать доступ к ним а могут нет. Настройки программ находятся **только** в директории текущего пользователя (*кто запускает*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В общем случае да, программы будут те же, но со стандартными настройками. Объясняется это тем, что они обычно хранят свои конфиги в домашнем каталоге пользователя, из-под пинка которого запускаются. Но, например, модули Python, установленные с помощью `pip` из-под пользователя, другим пользователям доступны не будут, так как все файлы он скачает по какому-то пути внутри домашней директории, которая другим пользователям обычно недоступна.
2. Можно, в современных Linux-дистрибутивах вовсю продвигают графические пакетные менеджеры - например, Synaptic, GNOME Software и множество других. В Ubuntu наверняка какой-то из них установлен по умолчанию, поищите в списке приложений.